# Get decoded title from Yoast SEO

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

Inside the Yoast settings, there are tags such as: Term Title, Page, Sitename etc.
And you can add them to title fields inside castom terms.
For example I want to get Woocommerce category Yoast title:

```
$catObj     = get_term_by( 'slug', 'my_woo_category_slug', 'product_cat' );
$seoTitle   = WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta::get_term_meta( $catObj, 'product_cat', 'title' );
```

But with my code I get string like: `%%term_title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%`
Is there any functions or tricks to get this string decoded from this tags? Just like this SEO plugin displays the title on any post page out of the box.

Comment: The replacing appears to be done by the class `WPSEO_Replace_Vars`, so go look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe in the comment helped me find the solution.
Working code for my issue:

```php
$catObj     = get_term_by( 'slug', 'my_woo_category_slug', 'product_cat' );
$seoTitle   = WPSEO_Taxonomy_Meta::get_term_meta( $catObj, 'product_cat', 'title' );
$cleanTitle = '';
$cleanTitle = wpseo_replace_vars( $seoTitle, $catObj );
```